# Converting 2D plots to 3D plots

Tags: java-2d

I have been working on some charts (like line chart, histogram, bar chart, pie chart, scattergram, radar chart, candle chart etc.) made in Java2D. I need to convert these charts into 3D charts without using Java3D API.
Is there any technique or algorithm available through which I may convert my 2D charts into 3D charts?
Or is anyone aware of any third party API (free or paid) available which can meet my requirement?
Any help or solution will be highly appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a technical reason preventing you from using Java3D?

Comment: @Tarik: I have not completely ruled out Java3D, but if a more straight forward technique is available that would be a preferred approach. Few technical reasons for this are:   

•As per my knowledge, Java3D development has been stopped on 2008. Further development perhaps then have been on scene graph in JavaFX.

•Java3D has the crashing issue on invoking from a remote machine. 

•Java3D in my opinion will be more resource intensive than Java2D. 

•I am slightly apprehensive that achieving the desired features and quality of plots would be relatively more complex in Java3D

Answer (score 2):

When you mention that you are creating plots and charts in Java2D, that implies that you are either creating these plots from scratch using your own coding or using ready made libraries such as jplot2d http://code.google.com/p/jplot2d/ or http://geosoft.no/graphics/. In either case, nothing will "convert" your Java2D charts to 3D charts. jzy3d jzy3d.org/ or TeeChart http://www.steema.com/teechart/java might do the job but will require to recode using their own APIs. Note that for pie charts and line charts, there is no point other than improving the look to go 3D. Only 3D data such as surfaces or contour plots need 3D.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. We are aware of TeeChart as it is already used in our other applications(.Net and Active X version though). It is good but the 3D part is perhaps not great. jzy3d looks interesting so we are in the process of downloading and trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

[Orson Charts](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/) is a 3D chart library for Java that renders using just the Java2D API.  It's written by the author of [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) (me), but it is not free - you can download an evaluation copy to try it out though.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at [Jzy3d](http://jzy3d.org).
It is free, open source, and easy to use. 
There are [tutorials](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/tree/master/jzy3d-tutorials) to learn how to draw surface and scatter plots.